# ERROR: attach: task_for_pid(23990) failed: '(os/kern) failure'

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

I start jstatd in server:

```
/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jstatd -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.19.150.82 \
-J-Djava.security.policy=/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jstatd.all.policy \
-J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true
```

When I using jvisualvm to monitor server,it throws :

```
ERROR: attach: task_for_pid(23990) failed: '(os/kern) failure' (5)
```

jvisualvm info:

```
Version: 

1.8.0_211 (Build 1390-170114); platform 20170114-unknown-revn

System: 

Mac OS X (10.14.5) , x86_64 64bit

Java: 

1.8.0_211; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Vendor: 

Oracle Corporation, http://java.oracle.com/

Environment: 

UTF-8; en_CN (visualvm)

User directory: 

/Users/dolphin/Library/Application Support/VisualVM/8u131

Cache directory: 

/Users/dolphin/Library/Caches/VisualVM/8u131

Clusters: 

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/visualvm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler

Visit https://visualvm.github.io for more information. Built on NetBeans Platform.
```